# Inverse of function given by equation $y = a - b \cdot \text{ln}(1-\frac{x}{c})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, inverse

This is probably a silly question, but how do I find the inverse of the function given by the equation $y = a - b \cdot \text{ln}(1-\frac{x}{c})$? I tried doing $\text{exp()}$ on both sides but I don't know how to cope with $\text{exp}(b\cdot\text{ln}())$. Is there a simple trick I forgot about?

Comment: $e^{a\ln b} = e^{\ln(b^a)}$.

Comment: There is a way to cope with that, but to keep things easier, get the $\ln$ subexpression alone on one side before you apply $\exp$.

Comment: To undo many functions applied in a sequence, undo them in the reverse order. You put on your socks, then your shoes; you remove your shoes, then your socks.

Comment: Unwrap *step* by *step*.  Take $\exp$ *when you get to it* but not before. $y=a-b\ln (1-\frac xc)\\ y-a=-b\ln(1-\frac xc)\\ \frac {-y+a}b=\ln(1-\frac xc)\\ e^{\frac{-y+a}b}=1-\frac xc\\ \frac xc=1-e^{\frac{-y+a}b}\\ x=c(1-e^{\frac{-y+a}b})$

Comment: But FWIW  $\exp(b\ln k) = e^{b\ln k} = (e^{\ln k})^b = k^b$.  So $y = a-b\ln(1-\frac xc)\\ e^y=e^{a-b\ln(1-\frac xc)}=\frac {e^a}{e^{b\ln(1-\frac xc)}}=\frac {e^a}{(1-\frac xc)^b}$ which I guess we can continue with $1-\frac xc =(\frac {e^a}{e^y})^{\frac 1b}=e^{\frac{a-y}b}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of immediately taking the exponential, I would proceed as follows.
$$
y = a - b \cdot \ln\left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right)\\
b \cdot \ln\left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right) = a-y\\
\ln\left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right) = \frac{a-y}{b}\\
1-\frac{x}{c} = \exp\left(\frac{a-y}{b}\right)\\
\frac{x}{c} = 1 - \exp\left(\frac{a-y}{b}\right)\\
x = c - c\exp\left(\frac{a-y}{b}\right)
$$

---

If you insist on using $\exp()$ as the first step, you could use the following simplification.
$$
\exp\left(a - b \cdot \text{ln}\left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right)\right) = \\
\frac{\exp(a)}{\exp \left(b \cdot \text{ln}\left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right)\right)} =\\
\frac{\exp(a)}{\exp \left(\text{ln}\left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right)\right)^b} =\\
\frac{\exp(a)}{\exp \left(1-\frac{x}{c}\right)^b}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

" Is there a simple trick I forgot about?"

Yes.  If $k = m\ln n$ then $e^k = e^{m\ln n} = (e^{\ln n})^m = n^m$.

So you can do it this way (although I do not advise it)

$y = a-b\ln(1-\frac xc)$

$e^y = e^{a-b\ln(1-\frac xc)}= \frac {e^a}{e^{b\ln(1-\frac xc)}}=\frac {e^a}{(1-\frac xc)^b}$

$(1-\frac xc)^b =\frac {e^a}{e^y}= e^{a-y}$

$1-\frac xc = e^{\frac {a-y}b}$

$\frac xc = 1-e^{\frac {a-y}b}$

$x = c(1-e^{\frac {a-y}b})$.

.....

Instead I'd advice unwrapping layer by layer

$y = a-b\ln(1-\frac xc)$

$y-a = -b\ln(1-\frac xc)$

$\frac {a-y}b =\ln (1-\frac xc)$

$e^{\frac {a-y}b} = 1-\frac xc$

$\frac xc = 1-e^{\frac {a-y}b}$

$x = c(1-e^{\frac {a-y}b})$.